# Display a Huge image in WPF application

Tags: wpf, image

I wish to display a HD size 1920X1080 image in my WPF application. When I set the image source in the image control, only part of the image is displayed, size of image control.

I do not wish to auto-fit the HD image into the image control. Say the image control is size 640 X 480 then the 640X480 of HD image should be displayed. But when I pan the image then the next 640 X 480 of the image should be displayed.
I already have implemented TransformGroup
 TransformGroup group = new TransformGroup();
            ScaleTransform xform = new ScaleTransform();
            group.Children.Add(xform);
            TranslateTransform tt = new TranslateTransform();
            group.Children.Add(tt);

But my problem is that entire image is not loaded initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is the ability to scroll your image...then use:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <Image Stretch="None" Source="c:\mytestimage.png" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

See these handy posts if you want to be more sophisticated/efficient:

- [WPF Image Zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639477/wpf-image-zooming)
- [Pan & Zoom Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741956/pan-zoom-image)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85603/A-WPF-custom-control-for-zooming-and-panning

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate way to display the image. Set the max-es on the image, so it wont visually load larger than what is needed.

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source}"
       Stretch="UniformToFill"
       MaxHeight="200"
       MaxWidth="400"/>
```

Image below shows two images loaded as is, a small one and a large one. The left side shows the large one exploding past the boundaries. The right one shows the proper shrinkage for the large one.

[image]

To keep the smaller image from *oversizing* (as shown on the right side) set the `StretchDirection="DownOnly"` to keep the smaller one from expanding.